# Blade @inject directive and variable inside

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need to pass variable with class path to @inject.

```
<?php 
     $path = "App\Widgets\\".$widget_name;
?>

@inject('widget', $path)
```

But i have an error: "Class $path does not exist"

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: I thing, it should be like this code @inject('widget', <?php echo $path;?>). $path is php veritable.

Comment: in this case i have an error "Undefined offset: 1"

Comment: is @inject angular js?

Comment: Does `@inject('widget', "App\Widgets\{$widget_name}")` work for you?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#service-injection

Comment: Use dd($widget_name) to see it $widget_name has what you expect

Comment: Dees Oomens 
it doesnt work. I got same error: "Class App\\Widgets\\{$widget_name} does not exist'

Comment: can you try this @inject('widget', "App\Widgets\{{$widget_name}}")

Comment: Class App\\Widgets\\<?php echo e($widget_name); ?> does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after some time of researching blade compiler)

```
<?php 
    $path = "App\Widgets\\".$widget_name;
    $widget = app($path);
?>
```

Where $widget will be your service class object.